# Swift: Generic protocol not conformed

Tags: swift, generics

I have create a protocol with generic function. When I try to implement the protocol I'm receiving the following error:

> Type 'MyListener' does not conform to protocol 'BaseDataListener'

How to fix it?
Thanks!

```
//the protocol
protocol BaseDataListener: class {
    func onDataLoaded<T>(_ items: [T])
}

//implementation
extension MyListener: BaseDataListener {
    func onDataLoaded(_ items: [MyModel]) {
        //so on
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm no expert in Swift, but your `onDataLoaded` method isn't generic but it is in the base?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the type for a generic function declaration if the protocol doesn't declare an `associatedtype`:

```
class MyModel {}
class MyListener {}

protocol BaseDataListener: class {
    func onDataLoaded<T>(_ items: [T])
}

extension MyListener: BaseDataListener {
    func onDataLoaded<MyModel>(_ items: [MyModel]) {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Approach-1**

Create **`associatedtype`** in `protocol` instead of using *generic parameter* `<T>` with the method `onDataLoaded(_:)`, i.e.

```
protocol BaseDataListener: class {
    associatedtype T
    func onDataLoaded(_ items: [T])
}

extension MyListener: BaseDataListener {
    func onDataLoaded(_ items: [MyModel]) {

    }
}
```

**Approach-2**

In case you want to associate *generic parameter* `<T>` with the method `onDataLoaded(_:)` only, use

```
extension MyListener: BaseDataListener {
    func onDataLoaded<MyModel>(_ items: [MyModel]) {

    }
}
```